# We need google to pick up videos that are not on the page initially but load later

Tags: video, google-search, pagespeed

Our website loads product videos on click to save load speeds, we also want our videos to be picked up by google search are we able to do it if the video is not on the page initially.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I voted to close this question because general SEO questions are off-topic. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.